# Swift NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns nil when 24hour off

Tags: ios, date, swift

I have this code to transform a string into a date:

```
extension String {
    func toDate(let format:String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", let timezone:NSTimeZone = NSTimeZone()) -> NSDate? {
        var formatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
        formatter.timeZone = timezone
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.dateFromString(self)
    }
}
```

This works fine on **24hour mode on**, but when i turn it off and i give it this string `2014-10-30 07:04`, it always returns nil. Any idea why?

Comment: From the referenced thread: You have to set the date formatters locale to "en_US_POSIX".